# extra indirection in C preprocessor stringification making difference

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

```
#define N 1

#define A(N) #N
#define S_A A(N)

#define B_(N) #N
#define B(N) B_(N)
#define S_B B(N)

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  puts(S_A);
  puts(S_B);
}
```

outputs `N` and `1` instead of two `1`s.

Why is the extra indirection making a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works different because the macro expansion of `N` only happens on the "use" of `N`. So `S_A` exands to `A(N)`, which is expanded to `#N`. In `S_B` it is expanded to `B(N)`, which is expanded to `_B(1)`, and then `#1`. Why? Well, how would you do something like:

```
 #define COMBINE(A, B)  A##B
 #define foo 1
 #define bar 2
 int COMBINE(foo, bar) = 34;
```

so that it generates `int foobar = 34;`, and not the illegal `int 12 = 34;`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to use a `## operator` for token pasting?

```
puts(S_A);  //Gets expanded into puts(A(N)) --> puts(#N)
```

and

```
puts(S_B);  //Gets expanded into puts(B(N)) --> puts(_B(1)) --> puts(#1)
```

Without affecting your macros much, if you intend to print `1,1` both the times, you could Use the macros this way:

```
#define N "1"     //instead of 1
#define A(N) N    //instead of #N
#define B_(N) N   //instead of #N
```